# Getting nil image even though the file exists in directory

Tags: ios, image, null, exists

I am saving an image from to my apps directory, and when I try to retrieve it with imageWithContentsOfFile it returns a nil image. I have verified that the file exists in the apps container and that the path I use is correct. Any ideas?

If there is any code that you need let me know. I am not sure what you would need to see.

Thanks

BTW here is the exact syntax I use for loading the image from the path.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Have you tried `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];`?

Comment: I have, and I get the same result.

Comment: When you say in your "apps directory", do you mean in the project navigator? If so, try dropping the image in `Images.xcassets` folder.

Comment: I do not mean the project navigator. The app downloads it and saves it in a tmp directory.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is to check is it a file input/output issue or an image issue. So try to read your file data with

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

If fileData is nil or its length is 0 then you should recheck the path and the way you are storing a data.

If fileData is ok try

```
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:fileData];
```

to check a data to image conversion. Is it possible to open file with some MacOS image viewer?

Comment: The data is fine, and when I use the initWithData method it still returns nil.

Comment: @linuxer Could you please add a code you use to save an image to a file?